# Measuring power usage of a C++ program

Tags: c++, power-management

I have a C++ program for which I need to measure the power consumption it uses. I first tried using Simplescalar and WATTCH, but neither worked. They did work for simple C programs, but when I tried them for simple C++ programs, I would get errors like "iostream not defined" (or something like that).

So first of all, has anyone gotten SimpleScalar (or WATTCH) to work with C++ programs? If so, could you please guide me to the exact instructions you followed? Because I have practically installed it around 20 times from different sources, but I always got the same error when compiling C++ programs.

Second, any suggestions for other tools I can use to simulate the power usage of a C++ program? I will be running my program on a Unix system.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to try to simulate power consumption when there's I/O in a program.  Which is surely the reason it doesn't care for iostream.

Comment: @HansPassant: ... apart that iostreams are not necessarily meant for i/o: a stringstream is an iostream, but there is no i/o there. Just like reading a memory mapped file from the memory does not produce i/o... Your conjecture is mixing up two different abstraction layers.

Comment: Are you compiling the program with static libraries?

Comment: After a quick googling, it seems it is not that easy (check [here](http://hpc.serc.iisc.ernet.in/~sree/resources/building-cross-gcc-for-simplescalar.html)). Besides that, unless you need to use SimpleScalar (a pretty old simulator), you may consider to use newer ones such as PTLSim, SESC, etc. I know it is possible to use C++ programs with newer simulators.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes I also tried it without including iostream but it still gave me an error...and as Emilio said, I am including iostream for stringstream and not to produce i/o...but thx anyways :)

Comment: @betabandido No I don't think I am compiling with static libraries. And thanks for the suggestions... It seems that PTLSim is what I want. Have you used either tool? Do you recommend one over the other?

Comment: @alguru I have used both, but only modified its internals for PTLsim, so I cannot really say which one is better. I believe SESC has a newer design, so it may be interesting to look at it. If you are doing a PhD, choosing a simulator is a very important decision, since most probably you will use that very same simulator for the rest of the PhD. BTW, I am assuming you need a simulator (i.e., you need to change some parameters from the architecture). If not, have you considered using a real machine?

Comment: @betabandido No I am not doing a PhD. This is for my undergraduate final year project. And no I don't need to change parameters from the architecture, but the purpose of this project is to show that a considerable difference in power between my two different algorithms is present. So I don't need exact numbers, and plus I don't currently have access to a real machine, so this is more than enough.. Thanks :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11786/discussion-between-alguru-and-betabandido)

Comment: Did you consider using an actual hardware electric meter to measure the power consumption on a clean idle system without your program and with it running and calculate the difference?